# Import fails for scikit learn package in Redshift UDF

Tags: python, scikit-learn, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I am trying to import scikit-learn library in Redshift but getting error:
'Not a directory', '/rdsdbdata/user_lib/1/0/627380.zip/sklearn/__check_build')

I followed below steps:

1. Downloaded 0.18.1/0.18.2 release of scikit-learn as this release requires: Python (>= 2.6 or >= 3.3),NumPy (>= 1.6.1),SciPy (>= 0.9) and redshift have Python 2.7, numpy 1.8.2, scipy 0.12.1.
2. Uploaded the sklearn zip file to s3
3. Created library in Redshift:

```
CREATE or replace LIBRARY sklearn 
LANGUAGE plpythonu FROM 's3://<path>/sklearn.zip' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<access_key>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret_key>';
```

4. Created function:

```
create or replace function f_py_scikit ()
  returns varchar
stable
as $$
  import sklearn
  return 'sklearn: {}'.format(sklearn.__version__)
$$ language plpythonu;
```

```
select f_scikit();

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: OSError: (20, 'Not a directory', '/rdsdbdata/user_lib/0/0/627380.zip/sklearn/__check_build'). Please look at svl_udf_log for more information

svl_udf_log:

   query    message created traceback   funcname    node    slice   seq
0   OSError: (20, 'Not a directory', '/rdsdbdata/user_lib/0/0/627380.zip/sklearn/__check_build') 1000   20000   0
```